# How to check session params in rspec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, rspec

When user visit some page on the site, his session marked with some values.

How I can check it with Rspec? I can't find any information about it.

Update: Rails 4.2.8

Answer (score -1):

You cannot access session[:some_key] in specs. Add this to spec/spec_helper.rb

```
def session
  last_request.env['rack.session']
end
```

This allows you to access the session from tests.

And if you use devise with :authenticate_user! action in controllers you might have to mock the authenticate_user method and return a fake user

Comment: This doesn't work fo me      Failure/Error: last_request.env['rack.session']
     
     NameError:
       undefined local variable or method `last_request' for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups::Nested::En::Utm:0x0000000a50ea88>
     # ./spec/spec_helper.rb:51:in `session'

Comment: Have you tried to access the session in your controller spec with just `request.session[:key]` ?